# Changing the ListView item height inside the onScroll() causes a warning

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Listview and I am changing the `ListView` item height dynamically inside the onScroll callback.

The issue is that I am having the following warning:

```
05-29 14:41:16.935: W/View(1629): requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.RelativeLayout{42701a80 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-768,600 #7f060133 app:id/parent} during layout: running second layout pass
```

And the `onScroll` callback is always being called, even after the user is not scrolling it, here is my code:

```
    listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (adapter != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < visibleItemCount; i++) {
                    //the listview view 
                    View v = adapter.getParentView(firstVisibleItem + i);
                    if (v != null) {
                        LayoutParams lp = v.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.height = //some height manipulation according to the view position
                        v.setLayoutParams(lp); //this line causes the warning
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

**My goal** is to change the listview items height by 1px every time depanding on the items position on the screen.

**Question:** how can I set the view `LayoutParams` inside the `onScroll` callback

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717022/trace-requestlayout-improperly-called?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @MohammadAbuQauod I have looked into those questions, I didn't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the solution was posting a runnable on the looper with the `setLayoutParams()` call.

```
v.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);                      
    }
});
```